# Finite Hankel transformation on a heat pot problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to use the Finite Hankel Transform to solve for $U(r,z)$ from the differential equation
$$
U_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}U_r+U_{zz} = 0
$$
the boundary conditions are $U(r,0)=c$ (constant), $U(1,z)=0, U(r,2) = 0$. Here's a diagram: [image]

I am first trying to apply the finite Hankel transformation, so we have
$$
H_j(U(r,z))=\int_0^1U(r,z)rJ_n(\mu_jr)dr$$
where $\mu_j$ are positive zeros of $J_n(\mu_j)=0$. Then am thinking about the inverse Hankel transformation. However, I'm not exactly sure how can I perform the Hankel transformation on the boundary conditions to solve this problem?

Also, when we are solving such boundary value problems, do we generally first apply the transformation on the differential equations, then for the boundary value conditions, to obtain the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: A more typical boundary condition would be $U_{r}(0)=0$.  This ensures that U is smooth at the origin.